# Why does __VA_ARGS__ variable macro expansion blows up with GCC 5.1 using forward-declared std::string?

Tags: c++11, gcc

```
In file included from ./../folly/FBString.h:59:0,
                 from ./../folly/Conv.h:27,
                 from detail/CacheLocality.cpp:23:
./../folly/Traits.h:155:38: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   struct IsRelocatable<  __VA_ARGS__ > : std::true_type {};
                                      ^
./../folly/Traits.h:221:3: note: in expansion of macro 'FOLLY_ASSUME_RELOCATABLE'
   FOLLY_ASSUME_RELOCATABLE(__VA_ARGS__<T1, T2, T3>) }                   \
   ^
./../folly/Traits.h:427:1: note: in expansion of macro 'FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE_3'
 FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE_3(std::basic_string);
 ^
./../folly/Traits.h:171:48: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   struct has_nothrow_constructor<  __VA_ARGS__ > : ::boost::true_type {};
                                                ^
./../folly/Traits.h:224:5: note: in expansion of macro 'FOLLY_ASSUME_HAS_NOTHROW_CONSTRUCTOR'
     FOLLY_ASSUME_HAS_NOTHROW_CONSTRUCTOR(__VA_ARGS__<T1, T2, T3>) }
     ^
./../folly/Traits.h:427:1: note: in expansion of macro 'FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE_3'
 FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE_3(std::basic_string);
 ^
./../folly/Traits.h:155:38: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   struct IsRelocatable<  __VA_ARGS__ > : std::true_type {};
                                      ^
./../folly/Traits.h:213:3: note: in expansion of macro 'FOLLY_ASSUME_RELOCATABLE'
   FOLLY_ASSUME_RELOCATABLE(__VA_ARGS__<T1, T2>) }               \
   ^
./../folly/Traits.h:429:1: note: in expansion of macro 'FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE_2'
 FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE_2(std::list);
 ^
./../folly/Traits.h:171:48: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   struct has_nothrow_constructor<  __VA_ARGS__ > : ::boost::true_type {};
                                                ^
./../folly/Traits.h:216:5: note: in expansion of macro 'FOLLY_ASSUME_HAS_NOTHROW_CONSTRUCTOR'
     FOLLY_ASSUME_HAS_NOTHROW_CONSTRUCTOR(__VA_ARGS__<T1, T2>) }
     ^
./../folly/Traits.h:429:1: note: in expansion of macro 'FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE_2'
 FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE_2(std::list);
 ^
Makefile:1395: recipe for target 'detail/CacheLocality.lo' failed
```

To me this looks fine, yet the compiler complains.

Comment: Let me break into your system, enter `./../folly` and check the code.

Comment: What's "this" that looks fine? All that's in your "question" is a dump of error messages. If that looks fine, then sure, keep it as it is, you'll continue getting those errors.

Comment: added details as an answer.....

Answer (score 0):

So the code above is simple enough. For reference folly is open source code that one can lookup, it's here:

https://github.com/xnox/folly/commit/ca2e9c7f1b6bf92f1f67ae627692547710932577

The core problem was that gcc claimed that "std::string" is ambigious...

However that sounds crazy right... well the code did a forward declaration of std::string, but dual-abi 98/11 libstdc++ diverts std::string to std::__cxx11::string via inline namespacing. Hence gcc started to see std::string as ambigious after the "non-inline namespace forward declare from userspace". Clearly this is broken behaviour and one shall not forward declare std::string, or any std::* stuff for that matter.